# CSS only popup - page moves when closing

Tags: html, css, popup

I am trying to create a CSS only welcome popup. Everything works fine except when you close it, the page shifts down to where the popup div would be originally. How can I fix it so that the page does not shift when you close the popup?

I am using the following....

http://codepen.io/john84/pen/WrOZJj

The HTML

```
<h1>Popup/Modal Windows without JavaScript</h1>
<div class="box">

<a class="button" href="#">Login /signup</a>
</div>

<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
<div class="popup">
<h2>Here i am</h2>
<a class="close" href="#popup1">&times;</a>
<div class="content">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eleifend nunc non malesuada feugiat. Fusce lacinia urna sed nunc accumsan viverra.
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
*, *:after, *:before {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
background: url(http://www.shukatsu-note.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/computer-564136_1280.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
text-align: center;
font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
color: #06D85F;
margin: 100px 0;
}

.box {
width: 40%;
margin: 0 auto;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
padding: 35px;
border: 2px solid #fff;
border-radius: 20px/50px;
background-clip: padding-box;
text-align: center;
}

.button {
font-size: 1em;
padding: 10px;
color: #fff;
border: 2px solid #06D85F;
border-radius: 20px/50px;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.button:hover {
background: #06D85F;
}

.popup h2 {
margin-top: 0;
color: #333;
font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
right: 30px;
transition: all 0.2s;
font-size: 30px;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
color: #06D85F;
}
.popup .content {
max-height: 30%;
overflow: auto;
}

/*Let's make it appear when the page loads*/
.overlay:target:before {
display: none;
}
.overlay:before {
content:"";
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
display: block;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
position: fixed;
z-index: 9;
}
.overlay .popup {
background: #fff;
border-radius: 5px;
width: 30%;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 35%;
padding: 25px;
margin: 70px auto;
z-index: 10;
-webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
.overlay:target .popup {
top: -100%;
left: -100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
.box{
width: 70%;
}
.overlay .popup{
width: 70%;
left: 15%;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
.overlay:target:before {
    display: none;
}
```

to

```
.overlay:target{
    display: none;
}
```

change

```
<div class="box">
<a class="button" href="#">Login /signup</a>
```

to

```
<div class="box" id='box'>
 <a class="button" href="#box">Login /signup</a>
```

This will force `:target` to focus on the button when it is clicked and display your box where the button is located . The `:target` pseudo usually add focus on element which it is linked to. this means  it will 'scroll up or down' the page to find that element. Useful link to understand how  this pseudo works is  [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_target.asp)

**Here is  working snippet (Limitation: no sliding of pop up box out of window as seen in your sample....)**

```css
*, *:after, *:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background: url(http://www.shukatsu-note.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/computer-564136_1280.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #06D85F;
  margin: 100px 0;
}

.box {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  padding: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #06D85F;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.button:hover {
  background: #06D85F;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: top,right 0.2s;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}

/*Let's make it appear when the page loads*/
#popup1:target{
     top: -100%;
    left: -100%;
    display:none;
}

.overlay:before {
  content:"";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9;
}
.overlay .popup {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 35%;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 70px auto;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
.overlay:target .popup {
    top: -100%;
    left: -100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
  .box{
    width: 70%;
  }
  .overlay .popup{
    width: 70%;
    left: 15%;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Popup/Modal Windows without JavaScript</h1>
<div class="box" id='box'>
 <a class="button" href="#box">Login /signup</a>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
 <div class="popup">
  <h2>Here i am</h2>
  <a class="close" href="#popup1">&times;</a>
  <div class="content">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eleifend nunc non malesuada feugiat. Fusce lacinia urna sed nunc accumsan viverra.
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping to keep the flyout animation but I can do without it.